# Python spsolve ValueError

Tags: python-2.7, valueerror

I am trying to solve a system in canonical form with spsolve.
Unfortunately, I get an error message that I do not understand.

**My code**

```
A11 = nablaTnabla + lamda*diag_Ix_squared
A12 = lamda*diag_Ix_Iy
A21 = lamda*diag_Ix_Iy
A22 = nablaTnabla + lamda*diag_Iy_squared 

b0 = lamda*(Ix*(Ix*u_0 + Iy*v_0 - It))
b1 = lamda*(Iy*(Ix*u_0 + Iy*v_0 - It))
A = np.matrix([[A11,A12],[A21,A22]])
b0 = b0.flatten()
b1 = b1.flatten()
b = np.array([b0,b1])
u,v = sp.linalg.spsolve(A,b)
```

I get the following error message for spsolve: 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

A has the shape: (2,2)
b has the shape: (2, 226592)

I do not know how to solve that error. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I was confusing sparse with dense matrices, so spsolve was not able to compute the system.
The variable diag_Ix_squared is a sparse matrix, so the rest needs to be one too.

```
  M = u.shape[0]
  N = u.shape[1]
  nabla = spnabla(M,N)
  nablaTnabla = nabla.T*nabla
  u_0 = u
  v_0 = v
  Ix_flat = Ix.flatten()
  Iy_flat = Iy.flatten()
  diag_Ix_squared = sp.spdiags(Ix_flat*Ix_flat, 0, M*N, M*N)
  diag_Ix_Iy = sp.spdiags(Ix_flat*Iy_flat, 0, M*N, M*N)
  diag_Iy_squared = sp.spdiags(Iy_flat*Iy_flat, 0, M*N, M*N)

  A11 = nablaTnabla + lamda*diag_Ix_squared
  A12 = lamda*diag_Ix_Iy
  A21 = lamda*diag_Ix_Iy
  A22 = nablaTnabla + lamda*diag_Iy_squared

  b0 = lamda*(Ix*(Ix*u_0 + Iy*v_0 - It))
  b0 = b0.ravel()
  b1 = lamda*(Iy*(Ix*u_0 + Iy*v_0 - It))
  b1 = b1.ravel()


  A = sp.bmat([[A11,A12],[A21,A22]])

  b =  np.concatenate((b0,b1))

  x = sp.linalg.spsolve(A,b)
  u = x[:M*N]
  v = x[M*N:]
  u = np.reshape(u, (M,N))
  v = np.reshape(v, (M,N))
```